# How to Increase minimum point value and the color of series in advanced accessible charts in Highcharts by making it traverse

Tags: highcharts

I need to change the series color to uniformly be green and when the data range is high ,say I have data from Oct 2018 to Sep 2021 for one data point and the other data is Aug 20 2021 to Aug 22 2021,
the latter looks very small and barely noticeable . At this instance I want to set the minimum width and shape to the smallest data point in advanced accessible graph. How do I do that.
Any suggestion is appreciated

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2uHF.png)
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qh9Xj.png)

Code:function DrawRemoteRequestPSRChart(seriesData, yAxisCategories) {

```
        // Define custom series type for displaying low/med/high values using boxplot as a base
        Highcharts.seriesType('lowmedhigh', 'boxplot', {
            keys: ['low', 'high'],
            tooltip: {

            }
        }, {
            // Change point shape to a line with three crossing lines for low/median/high
            // Stroke width is hardcoded to 1 for simplicity
            drawPoints: function () {
                var series = this;
                this.points.forEach(function (point) {
                    var graphic = point.graphic,
                        verb = graphic ? 'animate' : 'attr',
                        shapeArgs = point.shapeArgs,
                        width = 0,
                        left = Math.floor(shapeArgs.x) + 0.5,
                        right = left + width,
                        crispX = left + Math.round(width / 2) + 0.5,
                        highPlot = Math.floor(point.highPlot) + 0.5,
                        // Sneakily draw low marker even if 0
                        lowPlot = Math.floor(point.lowPlot) +
                            0.5 - (point.low === 0 ? 1 : 0);

                    if (point.isNull) {
                        return;
                    }

                    if (!graphic) {
                        point.graphic = graphic = series.chart.renderer
                            .path('point')
                            .add(series.group);
                    }

                    graphic.attr({
                        stroke: point.color || series.color,
                        "stroke-width": 4
                    });

                    graphic[verb]({
                        d: [
                            'M', left, highPlot,
                            'H', right,
                            'M', left, lowPlot,
                            'H', right,
                            'M', crispX, highPlot,
                            'V', lowPlot
                        ]
                    });
                });
            }
        });

        // Create chart
        var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
            chart: {
                type: 'lowmedhigh',
                inverted: true
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            }, legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Daily company fruit consumption 2019'
            },
            tooltip: {
                shared: false, formatter: function () {
                    return this.point.category + ', ' + new Date(this.point.options.low).toGMTString() +
                        ' to ' + new Date(this.point.options.high).toGMTString() + '.';
                }
            },
            accessibility: {
                point: {
                    descriptionFormatter: function (point) {
                        var ix = point.index + 1,
                            category = point.category,
                            from = new Date(point.low),
                            to = new Date(point.high);
                        return ix + '. ' + category + ', ' + from.toDateString() +
                            ' to ' + to.toDateString() + '.';
                    }
                },



                typeDescription: 'Low, high. Each data point has a low and high value, depicted vertically as small ticks.' // Describe the chart type to screen reader users, since this is not a traditional boxplot chart
            },

            xAxis: [{
                accessibility: {
                    description: 'Months of the year'
                },
                categories: ['January', 'February'],
                crosshair: true
            }],

            yAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'
            },

            responsive: {
                rules: [{
                    condition: {
                        minWidth: 550
                    },
                    chartOptions: {
                        xAxis: {
                            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb']
                        }
                    }
                }]
            },


            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    stickyTracking: true,
                    whiskerWidth: 5
                }
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Plums', color: 'lime',
                data: [
                    [1416528000000,
                        1417478400000
                    ],
                    [
                        Date.UTC(2014, 10, 1, 10, 16, 58),
                        Date.UTC(2014, 12, 2, 10, 16, 58)
                    ]]
            }, {
                name: 'Bananas',
                color: 'blue',
                data: [

                    [Date.UTC(2014, 10, 21, 10, 16, 58),
                    Date.UTC(2014, 11, 22, 10, 16, 58)
                    ],
                    [
                        Date.UTC(2014, 10, 15, 10, 16, 58),
                        Date.UTC(2014, 12, 12, 10, 16, 58)
                    ]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Apples',
                color: 'red',
                type: 'scatter',
                marker: { symbol: 'diamond' },
                data: [

                    [Date.UTC(2014, 10, 20, 10, 16, 58),
                    Date.UTC(2014, 11, 27, 10, 16, 58)
                    ],
                    [
                        Date.UTC(2014, 10, 24, 10, 16, 58),
                        Date.UTC(2014, 10, 24, 12, 17, 58)
                    ]
                ]
            }]
        });

        // Remove click events on container to avoid having "clickable" announced by AT
        // These events are needed for custom click events, drag to zoom, and navigator
        // support.
        chart.container.onmousedown = null;
        chart.container.onclick = null;


        //Highcharts.chart('GraphHere', {
        //    chart: {
        //        type: 'xrange'
        //    },
        //    credits: {
        //        enabled: false
        //    },
        //    legend: {
        //        enabled: false
        //    },
        //    tooltip: {
        //        pointFormat: ''
        //    },
        //    title: {
        //        text: 'Mass Remote Request PSR'
        //    },
        //    xAxis: {
        //        type: 'datetime'
        //    },
        //    yAxis: {
        //        title: {
        //            text: ''
        //        },
        //        categories: yAxisCategories,
        //        min: 0,
        //        max: 5,
        //        scrollbar: {
        //            enabled: true
        //        },
        //        reversed: true
        //    },
        //    series: seriesData
        //});
    }
```

Comment: Hi, what chart do you have in mind, can you show with an example? https://www.highcharts.com/demo

Comment: @SebastianHajdus . I am using advanced accessible charts . the first screenshot that I have attached contains the graph where the data point in red at the bottom is barely noticeable. It is because the data requested and the data received is on the same day . In this case I want to replace that with a symbol like circle or diamond . I tried editing the code by using the { name: 'Apples',color: 'red',type: 'scatter',marker: { symbol: 'diamond' })]]} properties but the legends and data get disturbed and shown in the second screenshot attached . i have attached the code as well.

Comment: @SebastianHajdus :I have attached both images in the question and also the code

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to add a point there using a scatter series, disable or hide the point you want to otherwise show in **chart.event.load** and redraw the chart.

```
chart: {
  events: {
    load: function() {
      var chart = this;
      chart.series[0].update({
        borderColor: 'green',
        pointWidth: 0,
      }, false);
      chart.redraw();
    }
  }
},
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sx2u0epw/

API References:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.scatter